# Pesquisa mySQL por data de criação dos registros

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Quero fazer uma pesquisa mysql por data de criação de todos os registros, ou seja, quero que mostre o registro e a data em que foi registrado.

Ja pesquisei mas oq sempre mostra é o **between** mas não é isso que eu procuro.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Até onde eu sei não existe uma forma _automática_ de fazer isso, é preciso criar uma coluna na tabela e alimentá-la, tipo [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913142/how-to-add-a-created-at-column-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

A sua aplicação tem que incluir a data de criação dos registros - a maior parte dos frameowrks e aplicação tem um mixin de "time-stamped model", ou equivalente, que pode ser usado nos seus modelos - nesses casos, os dados de criação e última alteração são colocados em colunas específicas nas suas tabelas.

E nesses casos é só fazer uma query por essa coluna, ou colocando essas colunas no order-by.

Se a aplicação que cria a tabela e inseriu os registros não fez isso, só com os dados no banco não é possível saber o horário de criação dos registros. Se o ID automático dos registros não for uma sequência (por exemplo, se for um UUID), nem mesmo a ordem de inserção pode ser recuperada.

Se por acaso for um banco de produção e tiver habilitado os logs gerais (não só os logs de erro) - nesse caso, os timestamps de inserção e alteração no banco provavelmente podem ser extraídos desses logs. No entanto, essa geração de logs não é ativa na configuração padrão (veja mais aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql)